# Will Apple service secondhand iPad still under warranty?

Tags: ipad, battery, warranty

I bought an iPad on eBay a few weeks ago. It's still covered under the original Apple warranty. There's a clear problem with the battery. Will the Genius Bar staff look at and service this device if I'm not the original owner? Do I have to disclose that I'm not the original owner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally saying that you've bought it as secondhand you're ok, even because, before they start working on it, they need to have "Find my iPhone" disabled so, if you have stolen that iPad, you wouldn't be able to disable that.